# Default size of SMALLINT, TINYINT etc. in MySQL

Tags: mysql

As per [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) documentation, default size of SMALLINT is 2 bytes. I just did this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    MYDATA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And when I do `describe MYTABLE;` I get:

> Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
>
> 'MYDATA', 'smallint(5) unsigned', 'NO', '', NULL, ''

Why is it creating MYDATA as smallint(5) ?

But if I do this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    MYDATA SMALLINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then it creates `smallint(2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats number in brackets is not a size in bytes.
See documentaion near https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

It is a number of digits allowed to store, maximum display width.
smallint(5) or smallint(2) both will take 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

an unsigned smallint has a max value of 65535 and uses 2 bytes regardless of what number is put in the () when declared.  The (5) you are referring to simply refers to the width of the field.

Answer (score 1):

The number in brackets is the display width (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

The default display width of an unsigned `smallint` is 5 because the smallest and largest numbers that can be stored are 0 and 65535. This is called `smallint(5)`

If had a signed `smallint`, the default display width needs to be 6 because the minus sign needs to be displayed when the minimum value of -32768 is stored.

This is also why the default `int` is an `int(11)` and the default `tinyint` is a `tinyint(4)` even though the largest positive values that can be stored are 10 digits long and 3 digits long respectively.